# OnMarkerDragStart is changing the marker original position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm creating an application with Google Maps v2. Everytime I take or select a picture, I create a custom Marker and add it to the map like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_INTENT) {
            Bitmap photo = createBitmap(data);
            Marker m = map.addMarker(photoMarker(lastKnownLatLng, photo));
            markersInMap.add(m);
            Log.d(TAG, "Marker created with " + m.getPosition().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if I want to delete the marker, I drag it to a trash can icon. If the marker touches the trash can icon, it removes itself from the map; that works fine. If the marker doesn't touch the trash can, it should return to its original position, but that fails. When I start dragging the marker, it seems like the position changes and it ends up slighly above the map.

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    trashImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    draggedMarkerOriginalPosition = marker.getPosition();
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMarkerDragStart with " + draggedMarkerOriginalPosition.toString());
}
```

These two methods dump the nex information in the logcat, so it's clear that the marker position changes when I start dragging, but I don't know why and really need to prevent this from happening:

```
Marker created with lat/lng: (19.3457139,-99.1522399)
OnMarkerDragStart with lat/lng: (19.35094919370183,-99.15169514715672)
```

This is my entire Activity code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MAP_ACTIVITY";
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_INTENT = 1;

    private GoogleMap map; 
    private Polyline gpsTrack; 
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment; 
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient; 
    private Uri imageUri;
    private LatLng lastKnownLatLng;
    private List<Marker> markersInMap = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageView trashImageView;
    private LatLng draggedMarkerOriginalPosition;

    private enum MapStatus {
        EXPANDED, NORMAL, MINIMIZED
    }

    private MapStatus mapStatus = MapStatus.NORMAL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        moveMapLocationButton();

        ImageButton down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.down_arrow);
        down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                animateDownMapView();
            }
        });

        ImageButton up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.up_arrow);
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                animateUpMapView();
            }
        });

        ImageView camara = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camara);
        camara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startImageChoosingIntent();
            }
        });

        Button finalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_finalizar_recorrido);
        finalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gpsTrack.setPoints(new ArrayList<LatLng>());
                for(Marker m : markersInMap) m.remove();
                markersInMap.clear();
            }
        });


        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        trashImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trash);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(new CustomMapTileProvider(getResources().getAssets())));

        LatLng calymayor = new LatLng(19.345822, -99.152274);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(calymayor));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(calymayor, 15));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.CYAN);
        polylineOptions.width(4);
        gpsTrack = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

    }


    private void moveMapLocationButton() {
        View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
    }


    private void animateDownMapView() {
        ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(mapFragment.getView());
        a.setDuration(250);

        if (mapStatus == MapStatus.NORMAL) {
            mapStatus = MapStatus.EXPANDED;
            a.setParams(mapFragment.getView().getLayoutParams().height, dpToPx(getResources(), pxToDp(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels)));
            mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(a);
        } else if (mapStatus == MapStatus.MINIMIZED) {
            mapStatus = MapStatus.NORMAL;
            mapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            0,
                            0.3333f
                    )
            );
        }
    }

    private void animateUpMapView() {
        if (mapStatus == MapStatus.NORMAL) {
            mapStatus = MapStatus.MINIMIZED;
            mapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            0,
                            0.04f
                    )
            );
        } else if (mapStatus == MapStatus.EXPANDED) {
            mapStatus = MapStatus.NORMAL;
            mapFragment.getView().setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            0,
                            0.3333f
                    )
            );
        }
    }

    private int pxToDp(int px) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return dp;
    }

    private int dpToPx(Resources res, int dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        updateTrack();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                googleApiClient, this);
    }

    private void startImageChoosingIntent() {
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String pickTitle = "Seleccionar";

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{takePhotoIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_INTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_INTENT) {
                Bitmap photo = createBitmap(data);
                Marker m = map.addMarker(photoMarker(lastKnownLatLng, photo));
                markersInMap.add(m);
                Log.d(TAG, "Marker created with " + m.getPosition().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap createBitmap(Intent data) {
        boolean isCamera;
        Bitmap photoTaken = null;

        if(data == null) {
            isCamera = true;
        } else {
            String action = data.getAction();
            if(action == null) {
                isCamera = false;
            } else {
                isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        if(!isCamera) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
        }

        try {
            photoTaken = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoTaken;
    }

    private MarkerOptions photoMarker(LatLng latlng, Bitmap bitmap) {
        return new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng)
                .draggable(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Utils.getMarkerBitmap(getBaseContext(), bitmap)));
    }

    private void updateTrack() {
        List<LatLng> points = gpsTrack.getPoints();
        points.add(lastKnownLatLng);
        gpsTrack.setPoints(points);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        trashImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        draggedMarkerOriginalPosition = marker.getPosition();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMarkerDragStart with " + draggedMarkerOriginalPosition.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        Point markerScreenPosition = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        int size = 0;
        if (overlap(markerScreenPosition, trashImageView)) {
            size = dpToPx(getResources(), 60);
        } else {
            size = dpToPx(getResources(), 40);
        }
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;
        trashImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        trashImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Point markerScreenPosition = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        if (overlap(markerScreenPosition, trashImageView)) {
            marker.remove();
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(draggedMarkerOriginalPosition);
            Log.d(TAG, "OnMarkerDragEnd with " + draggedMarkerOriginalPosition.toString());
        }
    }

    private boolean overlap(Point point, ImageView imgview) {
        int[] imgCoords = new int[2];
        imgview.getLocationOnScreen(imgCoords);
        boolean overlapX = point.x < imgCoords[0] + imgview.getWidth() && point.x > imgCoords[0] - imgview.getWidth();
        boolean overlapY = point.y < imgCoords[1] + imgview.getHeight() && point.y > imgCoords[1] - imgview.getWidth();
        return overlapX && overlapY;
    }

}
```

And these images show where the marker starts and where it ends after I drag and release the marker anywhere outside the trash can.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I came up with this solution. I'm not sure if it's the best, but it's working.

I changed:

```
 private List<Marker> markersInMap = new ArrayList<>();
```

To:

```
 private Map<Marker, LatLng> markersInMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then when I add the marker:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_INTENT) {
            Bitmap photo = createBitmap(data);
            Marker m = map.addMarker(photoMarker(lastKnownLatLng, photo));
            markersInMap.put(m, new LatLng(lastKnownLatLng.latitude, lastKnownLatLng.longitude));
            Log.d(TAG, "Marker created with " + m.getPosition().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, to set it back to its original position:

```
 @Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    trashImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Point markerScreenPosition = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    if (overlap(markerScreenPosition, trashImageView)) {
        marker.remove();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMarkerDragEnd " + "removed");
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(markersInMap.get(marker));
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMarkerDragEnd " + marker.getPosition().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This workaround is the only solution I have found for the same problem. Could you mark your answer as accepted so it can help others?